# How to verify whether an WebElement is displayed in the viewport using WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, scrollbar, visibility

**Consider the following scenario,**

1. The webpage is displayed along with a vertical scroll bar
2. Scroll bar is present at the bottom
3. WebElement 'Test' is present at the top of the page and is now not visible in the current view port.

**Functionality to be verified:**

Clicking 'Goto Top' link in the bottom of the page should scroll the page such that the  WebElement 'Test' gets displayed within the view port.

Please let me know how to verify whether an element is displayed in the current view port or not using WebDriver.

**Note:**
element.isDisplayed will always be true in the above case as the function checks the whole page rather than checking the current view port only.

Comment: Can you post the website url?

Comment: Please try this [link] (http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000049.htm#top). Look out for the 'Top' link in the page

Comment: using javascript, you can tell if the element is in the viewport.  Just google search on how to do that.  WebDriver allows for javascript execution so that is one option although slightly ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vel Ganesh - I dont know if this can be verified using selenium. But can be definitely done using Sikuli. You can check sikuli.org for details. Sikuli has a Java API and so can be integrated with WebDriver code as well.

Comment: With Sikuli you can test if the page really scrolled up or not. But with WebDriver you might be able to do a negative testing. If page is scrolled and if you do a findElement on the "Top" link then it will throw an error - elementNotVisible. Just a second thought idea.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the very last thing coming to my mind, I'd go for something like this:

1. get screenshot on whatever you have after clicking the link at the bottom (make sure it gives you view port screenshot only)
2. use Webdriver's `window.scrollTo`  to go to top (see bellow)
3. repeat the 1.st step
4. compare the results of the 1.st and 3.rd step

Where for scrolling using webdriver should work following:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,0)");
```

It seems like a desperate workaround, but might be worth an effort if no other solution is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
   * This function determines if the YOffset ot top of the element falls between the top of the
   * client window and the bottom of the client window to determine if it's in the viewport.
   * @param selector
   * @return bool
   */
  async isElementInViewPort(selector) {
    // Get the needed  element dimensions using webdriver
    const elemLocation = await selector.getLocation();
    const elemTopBoundY = await elemLocation.y;
    // Get the needed client dimensions using javascript
    const winUpperBound = await this.driver.executeScript('return window.pageYOffset');
    const winHeight = await this.driver.executeScript('return document.documentElement.clientHeight');
    const winLowerBound = winUpperBound + winHeight;
    if (winUpperBound <= elemTopBoundY
      && winLowerBound >= elemTopBoundY) {
      return true;
    } return false;
  }

  /* waitForElementisinViewPort
   * This function determines if the YOffset ot top of the element falls between the top of the
   * client window and the bottom of the client window after an action such as a scroll.
   * The wait avoids trying to do anything before the element is in the viewport.
   * @param selector
   * @state selector
   * @param timeout
   * @return bool
   */
  async waitForElementToBeinViewPort(selector, state, timeout) {
    try {
      let isInViewpPort;
      await this.driver.wait(async () => {
        const bool = await this.isElementInViewPort(selector);
        isInViewpPort = bool;
        return bool === state;
      }, timeout);
      return isInViewpPort;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Function: waitForElementToBeinViewPort failed ${err} `);
      return null;
    }
  }

Example test

  const links = [{ link: 'All Web hosting deals', selector: coupons.selector.COUPON_DEALS_WEB },
    { link: 'Domain name deals', selector: coupons.selector.COUPON_DEALS_DOMAIN },
    { link: 'How do you redeem these coupons', selector: common.baseselector.FOOTER_CTA }];

  describe('Coupons Page Extra Links section', () => {
    links.forEach(async (link, i) => {
      it('Click each Extra Links section link and verify an expected element is scrolled to', async () => {
        await coupons.visit(page = '/coupons');
        const nav = await driver.findElement(common.baseselector.mainNav);
        // Need a scroll to top so that other tests don't leave the element under test off the page initially.
        await driver.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', nav);
        const linksToClick = await coupons.getExtraPlanLinks();
        const element = await driver.findElement(links[i].selector);
        await assert.isFalse(await coupons.waitForElementToBeinViewPort(element, false, timeout),
          `element ${link.selector} should not be in the viewport`);
        await linksToClick[i].click();
        const bool = await coupons.waitForElementToBeinViewPort(element, true, timeout);
        assert.isTrue(bool, ` element ${link.selector} should be in the viewport`);
      });
    });
  });
```